# How thick is the colored oxide layer on heat treated stainless steel?

Tags: metallurgy, surface-chemistry, oxides

When stainless steel is welded, or just heat treated, it will develop a thicker oxide layer, which in some cases is is rainbow colored, but can become so thick as to appear almost black. From the colors (diffraction effects, I assume), the nicer-looking layers must be on the order of a wavelength of light. Is there any more numerical information on their thickness?

Follow-up question: The colored oxide layers can be removed with a pickling paste (based on HCl) or a passivating cleaner (based on HNO$_3$ plus HF), but the resulting surface is much rougher than the original. Well, it is observably rougher if the original surface before heat treating was mirror-smooth. We call the new surface *satinized*. Is there any simple way to estimate surface roughness/surface area of the satinized surface?

Further follow-up: would the surface chemistry be expected to change due to the surface area increase (perhaps like shiny Pt vs platinized Pt (~340 mV): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum_black

Comment: You may have already found this reference: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/288376834.pdf

Comment: @Andrew 's source, Figure 2, seems like it might be compared to an [ultramicrotome section reference chart](https://www.vcbio.science.ru.nl/images/09-tem-sectionthickness_zoom.jpg) from [Radboud University's EM class](https://www.vcbio.science.ru.nl/en/fesem/tem/).  But I don't know which nodules or layer(s) you're comparing, or whether other factors like refractive index affect the spacing distance for structural color.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you very much!! Great reference!

Comment: @Mike Serfas:  Great color chart! Thank you!

Comment: I understand that they are related issues, but you might want to break up your question into one about structure and another about reactivity.

Comment: @Buck Thorn: I will. Yep, once I started asking, I couldn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

Not very thick. Carbon steel develops the same colors at much lower temperature/ times . Gold to pink to blue to purple , stainless shows the colors better because the base metal is brighter . It is caused by the thickness of oxides , a matter of a few layers of oxide molecules ; unfortunately I cannot give you a number in microns and can't remember which book it is in.